# UICollectionViewCell fails to relayout its subviews when UICV layout is invalidated

Tags: layout, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I wrote a more [detailed blog post](http://aplus.rs/2015/uicollectionviewcell-woes-with-bounds-change/) on this problem, but here's the gist. I have embedded UICollectionView inside another UIViewController. When the container view changes its bounds, collection view also changes its bounds, which trigger its UICollectionViewLayout to re-layout as well.

All is well except that cells do not re-use new frame and layout using old bounds.
This is the log from important methods, where it's obvious that layoutSubviews is using wrong (old) frame.

```
__57-[RTColumnViewController processCalculatorKeypadVisible:]_block_invoke

-[RTUnitLayout shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:] : YES, {{0, 1014}, {272, 375}} -> {{0, 1014}, {175, 375}}
-[RTUnitLayout prepareLayout], bounds={{0, 1014}, {175, 375}}, itemsize={175, 89}
-[RTUnitLayout prepareForAnimatedBoundsChange:] : {{0, 1014}, {272, 375}} -> {{0, 1014}, {175, 375}}

-[RTUnitLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:] : rect={{0, 667}, {175, 1334}}
__50-[RTUnitLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]_block_invoke_2 : <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000048016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9} frame={{0, 801}, {175, 89}}
__50-[RTUnitLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]_block_invoke_2 : <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000058016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 11} frame={{0, 979}, {175, 89}}
...

-[RTUnitLayout finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:] : <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000058016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 11} frame={{0, 979}, {272, 89}}
-[RTUnitLayout initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:] : <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000058016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 11} frame={{0, 979}, {175, 89}}
-[RTUnitCell layoutSubviews] : pre-super: {{0, 979}, {272, 89}}
-[RTUnitCell layoutSubviews] : post-super: {{0, 979}, {272, 89}}
...

-[RTUnitLayout finalizeAnimatedBoundsChange] : {{0, 1014}, {175, 375}}

__57-[RTColumnViewController processCalculatorKeypadVisible:]_block_invoke623 : completed
```

After it's done, if I just lightly scroll the UICV, it will trigger re-display and all cells will be shown as they should be. I'm just stumped why this does not happen during the original animation, when it should.

Any ideas..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got back from Apple engineers. If you have custom subclass of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, don't make a stupid mistake like I did and return YES form isEqual: method.

It must be:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
...
return [super isEqual:other];
}
```

More details in my [blog post](http://aplus.rs/2015/uicollectionviewcell-woes-with-bounds-change/).